# Can't seem to get shadowbox to work

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox, shadowbox

Ive ran into a problem getting anything with shadowbox to work. Here is the top of the page:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Beginning Android</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init();
</script>
</head>
```

And here is the pic I'm trying to run.

```
<p class="NormalText"><center><a href="android-robot-logo2.jpg" rel="shadowbox"><imgsrc="android-robot-logo2.jpg"/></a>
 </center></p>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<imgsrc="android-robot-logo2.jpg"/>
```

Should be:

```
<img src="android-robot-logo2.jpg"/>
```

[Try validating you html first.](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: It is... thats just a wrap around. Thanks for trying. Any other ideas?

Comment: Also validating comes back with no errors in the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver was using html 1 strict. Switched to html 5 and everything works.